# Resize Image in a word c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I converted my Docx from the **"Letter format"** to **"A4"** but now the Layout options are off. And I would like to change that via code

```
  var wordApplication = new Application();
        var document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\test.docx");


        //Set paper Size
        document.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;

        //Set paper Format
        document.PageSetup.PageHeight = 855;
        document.PageSetup.PageWidth = 595;


        //Doc save
        document.Save();

        //Close word
        wordApplication.Quit();[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I tried to use the PageSetup Height and Width and yes the values are in "Points" would be 30 and 21 cm. But that does not seam to be the right thing. Here is option in word that I would like to change via [image: code]

Comment: That dialog refers to shapes/images. What is it that you want to change the size of?

Comment: @DirkVollmar Of that shape/image it should fit into a A4 page

Comment: You are first setting to A4 and then explicitely setting `PageHeight`and `PageWidth`? Doesn't sound right to me, especially not the centimeter sizes shown in your screenshot. The width of an A4 page is 97.2% that of Letter while its length is 106.5% that of Letter. So in terms of "does it fit", you're main concern would be width. Setting to 97.2% width should suffice if the page margins are still the same. That said, you also need to determine the relative position of the shape and compare its position + height to the remaining height of that page. Also: Shapes or InlineShapes or both?

Comment: @LocEngineer I think too that Shpes would be the right way to go got maybe a example suing my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

OK, this one took some tinkering. trouble with shapes is that they retain their relative page position when you cut and paste them, so cutting from page bottom and pasting on the next page would paste them at the page bottom, not at the top.

To fix this, I re-set the shape position to top left before cutting:

```
var maxHeight = doc.PageSetup.PageHeight - doc.PageSetup.BottomMargin;
foreach (Word.Shape shape in doc.Shapes)
{
    //scale to 97.2%
    shape.Width = (float)0.972*shape.Width;
    shape.Height = (float) 0.972*shape.Height;

    var pos = (float)shape.Anchor.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage];
    var curPage = (int)shape.Anchor.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber];
    if (pos > maxHeight)
    {
        //Re-set position of shape to top left before cut/paste:
        shape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage;
        shape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage;
        shape.Left = WdApp.InchesToPoints((float)0.889);
        shape.Top = WdApp.InchesToPoints((float)0.374);
        shape.Select();
        WdApp.Selection.Cut();
        WdApp.Selection.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, curPage + 1);
        WdApp.Selection.Paste();
    }
}
foreach (Word.InlineShape inline in doc.InlineShapes)
{
    //scale to 97.2%
    inline.Width = (float)0.972 * inline.Width;
    inline.Height = (float)0.972 * inline.Height;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you effort !!!! But there is no text to be worried about only one image, So i can simply ignore the "'if's" and how to do that ?

Comment: hmm strange but the shape is not change its size stays the same .. and I do think that it is a InlineShape

Comment: Are you sure? 97.2% is pretty close to original size. Might just appear the same. Check the size of the shape in its properties.

Comment: 100 % sure since the if foreach is not getting triggered bc it is InlineShape  not a Shape

Comment: Now you got me confused. Inline shapes run with text. Since text cannot go beyond the margin, the layout should not be affected - other than by size. I have re-added the inline shape portion with resize. Oh: and yes, ignore the ifs then. Leaving them in for others.